# How to make a looping to make td rowspan?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new in blazor, so here is the thing.
I have same value from td and want to make a looping where the value will be displayed as a row span,
here is my example on image

**example**

[image]
[image]

That's is why i want to know how to do it here is my code

**Table**

```
    <div class="overflow-auto d-flex" style="height: 500px;" id="crewstable">
        @foreach (var item in StudioTables)
        {
            <table class="table table-striped table-borderd">
                <thead class="table-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="align-middle text-center" rowspan="2" style="width: 50px">Jam</th>
                        <th colspan="6"><div class="text-center align-middle">@item.days_name @item.days @item.month_name @item.year</div></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center" scope="col">sto 1</th>
                        <th class="text-center" scope="col">sto 3</th>
                        <th class="text-center" scope="col">sto 5</th>
                        <th class="text-center" scope="col">sto 7</th>
                        <th class="text-center" scope="col">sto 9</th>
                        <th class="text-center" scope="col">sto 11</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    var totalItemStudioOne = 0;
                    var totalItemStudioThree = 0;
                    var totalItemStudioFive = 0;
                    var totalItemStudioSeven = 0;
                    var totalItemStudioNine = 0;
                    var totalItemStudioEleven = 0;
                @for (int i = 0; i < item.hourly.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @if(item[i].hourly.studio_one.show_name == item[i-1].hourly.studio_one.show_name)
                        {
                            totalItemStudioOne++;
                            <td rowspan="totalItemStudioOne">Dummy</td>
                        }else{

                        }
                        @if(item[i].hourly.studio_three.show_name == item[i-1].hourly.studio_three.show_name)
                        {
                            totalItemStudioThree++;
                            <td rowspan="totalItemStudioThree">Dummy</td>
                        }else{

                        }
                        @if(item[i].hourly.studio_seven.show_name == item[i-1].hourly.studio_seven.show_name)
                        {
                            totalItemStudioFive++;
                            <td rowspan="totalItemStudioFive">Dummy</td>
                        }else{

                        }
                        @if(item[i].hourly.studio_five.show_name == item[i-1].hourly.studio_five.show_name)
                        {
                            totalItemStudioSeven++;
                            <td rowspan="totalItemStudioSeven">Dummy</td>
                        }else{

                        }
                        @if(item[i].hourly.studio_nine.show_name == item[i-1].hourly.studio_nine.show_name)
                        {
                            totalItemStudioNine++;
                            <td rowspan="totalItemStudioNine">Dummy</td>
                        }else{

                        }
                        @if(item[i].hourly.studio_eleven.show_name == item[i-1].hourly.studio_eleven.show_name)
                        {
                            totalItemStudioEleven++;
                            <td rowspan="totalItemStudioEleven">Dummy</td>
                        }else{

                        }
                    </tr>
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
    </div>
```

I would like to use another int outside off looping to make a rowspan but i think blazor didn't provide it so the code above just exampe and have many error
How can i solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Ricky.

This isn't really a Blazor problem.  I can see that basically, you understand how Blazor would use loops to generate content.  However, the way you are generating the underlying data is a bit of a mess.

You should have something like:

```
class Studio // describes whatever you want about the studio{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    // And whatever else describes the studio
}
class StudioTime{
    public int StudioID {get; set;}
    public int StartHour {get; set;}
    public int HoursLong {get; set;}
}
```

Then when you're building your table, your rowspan value is already known.